# Encoding problem when using smartdiagramset

Tags: input-encodings, smartdiagram

I am having problems with acute accentuation at i letter (the acute accentuation is í) after using the command

```
\smartdiagramset{uniform color list=gray!60 for 4 items}
```

after which all í's are changed with the letter 4 with an acute accent on the top of it.

See the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twosides, letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}

Testing the acute accent í í í ...

\smartdiagramset{
uniform color list=white!50!gray for 4 items,
circular distance=3cm,
text width=3cm,
planet text width=3.75cm,
}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{
A,B,C,D}
\caption{}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


Testing the acute accent í í í ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Which compiler do you use to get this issue? (I can't reproduce the issue.)

Comment: I use the command

pdftex 1.40 (UBUNTU 14.04)

Comment: See the compiled version:
https://www.ime.usp.br/~patriota/USP/Test.pdf

Comment: I didn't know that `pdflatex` can deal with these, I thought you need to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` (but I am not an expert on this). At least when I compile with `xelatex` I cannot reproduce your issue (but the output is not what one may expect either).

Comment: Please try to compile this:
https://www.ime.usp.br/~patriota/USP/Test.tex

Thank you very much!!

Comment: smartdiagram uses \i in loop without guarding it in a group. As \i is part of the definition of í in OT! it breaks. You can use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as a work-around.

Comment: Well actually I think it is a tikz bug.

Comment: Just changing to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as Ulrike said solves it. Why do you want to use another encoding? Besides, it's `twoside`, not `twosides`, and it's the default for the book class, so you don't need to load it.